# Getting web.config file error and 500 error in godaddy after uploading my web files to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-config

```
<configuration>

<system.net>

<mailsettings>

<smtp deliverymethod="Network" from="gdkpavan@gmail.com">

<network defaultcredentials="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" password="nprao@1111" port="587" username="pranayn5@gmail.com">

</network></smtp>

</mailsettings>

</system.net>

<appsettings>

<add key="con" value="Data Source=moviemaster.db.10502677.hostedresource.com; Initial Catalog=picketmaster; User ID=picketmaster; Password=Picket@500;">

</add></appsettings>

<connectionstrings>

<system.webserver>

<httperrors errormode="Detailed">

<asp scripterrorsenttobrowser="true">

</asp></httperrors></system.webserver>

<system.web>

<compilation debug="true" targetframework="4.0">

<assemblies>

<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">

<add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A">

<add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089">

</add></add></add></assemblies>

</compilation>

<authentication mode="Windows">

<customerrors mode="Off">

<compilation debug="true">

</compilation></customerrors>

<pages clientidmode="AutoID" controlrenderingcompatibilityversion="4.0">

</pages></authentication></system.web>

<system.web>

<sessionstate mode="InProc" timeout="15">

</sessionstate></system.web>

</connectionstrings></configuration>
```

When I tried to connect the database with this string from my local system the error lies in the connection string.

I tried to change the custom errors content off and added detail error still the error persists. And I am a beginner in asp.net I've developed a website and I've uploaded for the testing purpose, I want to see the error detail clearly what changes need to be done that web page.

After publishing the website I can't see the app code in the folder what would be the reason is that the reason for errors

please check this link http://www.ticket65.com/test

Thanks in Advance

Comment: in your web.config you've turned off custom error, can you check your iis setting -> .NET error pages?

Comment: iam using godaddy shared hosting how can i check that thank for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
machine.config.comments usually located in 
\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\vx.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
           <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="contactus@XXXXXXX">
               <network host="XXXXXXXXX" port="25"    userName="noreply@XXXXXXX password="XXXXXX" defaultCredentials="true"/>
        </smtp>

        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
    <appSettings>
    <add key="con" value="Data Source=XXXXXXX; Initial Catalog=XXXXXXX; User ID=XXXXXXXX; Password=XXXXXXX;"/>

    <!--<add key="SentMail" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>-->
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings/>
<system.web>
    <!-- 
        Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
        symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
        affects performance, set this value to true only 
        during development.
    -->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--
        The <authentication> section enables configuration 
        of the security authentication mode used by 
        ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
        The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
        of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
        during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
        it enables developers to configure html error pages 
        to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.
```

-->

```
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
     </system.webServer>
    <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
     -->
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="15"/>
    </system.web>
   </configuration>
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your code, only code is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You have the connection string inside the appsettings section of the configuration file, it should be inside the connectionstrings section.

Beyond that, your web.config file has a number of other issue with keys in the wrong locations, mismatched end elements, malformed xml etc. Two important things to remember when working with a web.config file are that the file must be well formed, valid xml and the element and attribute names are cases sensitive. In other words `<mailSettings>` is a valid element name but `<mailsettings>` is not.

I would suggest you refer to [system.web Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dayb112d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [How to: Read Connection Strings from the Web.config File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [system.webServer Section Group [IIS Settings Schema]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689429.aspx)

I've corrected all the errors I could find in in my sample below. It does make certain assumptions (such as you being on IIS7 and using an app pool running the .net 4.0 framework.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="gdkpavan@gmail.com">
                <network defaultCredentials="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" password="nprao@1111" port="587" userName="pranayn5@gmail.com" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=moviemaster.db.10502677.hostedresource.com; Initial Catalog=picketmaster; User ID=picketmaster; Password=Picket@500;" />
    </connectionStrings>

    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
      <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true" />
    </system.webServer>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <pages clientIDMode="AutoID" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
        <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="15" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I had a small error in the <assemblies> element that I have fixed in the answer. This still might not work without additional tweaking by you depending on the exact setup of your webserver with godaddy.com and your website. Based on your question it almost sounds like godday has custom errors turned on at the machine level but you should be able to debug any additional web.config issues on your local machine. One thing to doublecheck is to make sure you are running in an app pool that uses .net 4.0 as both the assembly and pages values are specifically referencing that version of .net.

Comment: i checked with godaddy am using asp.net 4.0 and same with the godaddy please can u help more about this error am scratching my head to resolve this error. thanks in advance